# is there any good source of anti-patterns?

Tags: java, anti-patterns

I've heard and read many materials for design patterns, coding styles, programming techniques, etc... but seldom read anti-patterns materials. I think reading those materials can learn a lesson in a "negative" way, such that it's meaningful for programming newbies to avoid common mistakes. And in fact not only newbies, some experienced programmers still writing horrible codes.

So, I would like to know any materials about this topic, please leave your suggestions here, thanks!

Comment: Most of the programs I've written are a good source for this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it's a good start for newbies:
http://www.odi.ch/prog/design/newbies.php

Answer (score 4):

Go example by example...

http://javaantipatterns.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 3):

common mistakes <s>here:
http://www.mydeveloperconnection.com/html/java_common_mistakes.htm</s> (dead link)

<s>and</s> here:
http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/articles/toptenerrors.html